# How to make WPF DataGrid NewItemPlaceholder always visible

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Took me days to find the answer to this simple question. I wanted to make so when I initialize a new row then the NewItemPlaceholder appear immediately.

NewItemPlaceholder is also known as a blank row - the row which is used to add new item into the DataGrid.

Will follow up with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also shape your new item in the **InitializingNewItem** callback method using the **e.NewItem** property so you can have correct item when the edit is commited.

**InitializingNewItem** is fired first following by **BeginningEdit** event.
Note that for the NewItemPlaceholder to appear you should also bind DataGrid to an editable collection with the default constructor declared and set **DataGrid.CanUserAddRows** property to true.

```
private bool _justCreatedNewItem;
dataGrid.BeginningEdit += (o, e) =>
{
  if (_justCreatedNewItem)
  {
     dataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
     _justCreatedNewItem = false;
  }
};
dataGrid.InitializingNewItem += (o, e) => { _justCreatedNewItem = true; };
```

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I needed!